# Javascript is not working while testing with selenium, site_prism and capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, site-prism

I am writing specs with capybara and selenium . I am able to run all the tests successfully but i am running through an issue. Js is not working at all in all of the specs. Can anyone help me in finding the way of running javascript?

Comment: Please, provide more information on what's exactly your issue. Your question is too broad and does not show any effort. Post your code, what does it mean "not working"?

Please, edit your question.

Comment: Show an example of your tests and your Capybara configuration